# Django: SQL Injection-proof managers.py

Tags: python, django, django-managers

I have a managers.py file that uses the .extra() parameter to perform raw SQL queries. For example:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):

    def order_null_last(self, field):
        return super(DecisionManager, self).get_query_set()\
            .extra(select={'has_field': "CASE WHEN " + field + " IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"}).order_by('has_field', field)
```

It's been suggested to me that this kind of query could be vulnerable to attack by injection.

The variable 'field' is parsed to make sure it belongs to a group of legitimate values, but this checking is done in the view. Eg:

```
class ModelList(ListView):
    model = MyModel

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.set_sorting(request)

    def set_sorting(self, request):
        self.sort_field = request.GET.get('sort', '-id')
        if not self.sort_field in self.sort_options:
            self.sort_field = 'id'
```

So if someone wrote a new view using the above manager but they forgot to filter the parameters then the exploit would be possible.

So, is there a way to validate a parameter against a models fields in the manager without getting circular imports? That is, the manager needs to import the model to get a list of permitted fields, but the model needs to import the manager.

Comment: The good news: Django checks that the fields given to order_by are valid on the query's model, so although you could construct invalid SQL in your call to extra, the ORM will throw an exception before trying to execute it. The bad news: This is fragile and I wouldn't want to rely on it. (Also, I think this doesn't work if you want to sort in reverse.)

Comment: That's good advice thanks. Oh and reverse sorting works for me.

Answer (score 1):

Using select_params in extra avoids sql injection:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):

def order_null_last(self, field):
    return super(DecisionManager, self).get_query_set()\
        .extra(select={'has_field': "CASE WHEN %s IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"}, select_params=(field,)).order_by('has_field', field)
```

Comment: Interesting. What does select_params do that means it avoids sql injection?

Comment: It quotes the parameter as needed for your database. However, I'm not sure it quotes it appropriately for a field name; I think it'll just quote it into a string literal. Try it and see?

Comment: OK yes I can see that the field is quoted in the SQL query. Eg <code>SELECT (CASE WHEN '-last_modified' IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ...</code>. Does this (select_params) offer anything more than if I'd just put quotes around the field in my manager function?

Comment: select_params cannot be used to pass in column names, only values.

Answer (score 0):

The model manager has access to the models, and therefore fields through self.model.

So I can write this:

class MyManager(models.Manager):

```
def order_null_last(self, field):
    if field in [modelfield.name for modelfield in self.model._meta.fields]:
        return super(DecisionManager, self).get_query_set()\
            .extra(select={'has_field': "CASE WHEN " + field + " IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END"}).order_by('has_field', field)
    else:
        return super(DecisionManager, self).get_query_set()
```